# knitr::kable not adding cross reference labels to tables in output

Tags: r, knitr

I have the following R code chunk in a bookdown document:

````
```{r list-organisms, include = TRUE, echo = FALSE, as.is = TRUE}
data %>%
  dplyr::select(biological_source_name) %>%
  unique() %>%
  dplyr::rename("Biological Source" = biological_source_name) %>%
  knitr::kable(caption = "List of source microbial genomes used in the benchmarks.", booktabs = TRUE)
```
````

In the document I am using cross references such as:

```
listed in Table \@ref(tab:list-organisms).
```

However these are not being found and I getting `??` throughout for the document. The generated html looks like:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr class="header">
<th align="left">Biological Source</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd">
<td align="left">T. composti</td>
</tr>
...
```

The table caption is also not appearing either.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. In bookdown `knitr::kable` documents don't output correctly when the table only contains a single column. Adding additional columns to the table generated the legend and fixed the cross references.